# Store data locally instead of fetching it on every app start

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

To fetch data on app init I use `APP_INITIALIZER`. To show the page just when the data is loaded, I return a promise that will resolve.

It works fine, but doing so data is fetched on every reload, hence there will be a promise to resolve each time, which leads to a delay for the user to enter the web-app.

Is there a bypass? I definitely need this data from the beginning, but it’s not necessary to be real-time.

*What about caching?* To enable caching for each document, I used `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()`. But how do I get the cached data and if there’s none, how do I load it from Firestore instead?

AppInitService:

```
Init(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.db.collection('entries').valueChanges()
    .subscribe(val => {
      this.casesService.data = val;
      resolve(true);
    });
});}
```

app.module.ts

```
export function initializeApp1(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return appInitService.Init();
  };
}

providers: [
   AppInitService,
   { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp1, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true }
],
```

Comment: just try to store your data inside the browser local storage for ex. localStorage.setItem('dataSource', this.dataSource.length);

Comment: @MiteshSawant Ok but afterwards, how do I check whether there is data, and if not load it from firestore instead?

Comment: not just only store data in browser local storage you can retrieve data also this may help this.storage.get(key)